# Separate OAuth for a mobile app accessing a RESTful service?

Tags: facebook, rest, oauth

I have a mobile app that authenticates a user via a facebook login. This app then communicates with a RESTful php web service. Now, I know that facebook uses an OAuth dialog and a user session is created. Do I use facebook's OAuth token and authorize a user session, or do I have to have OAuth in my web service separately to  manage user sessions.